# linux curlftpfs, password with symbols

Tags: linux, ftp, curlftpfs

I want to mount an FTP drive, but my FTP password contains "?!".

I enter the command:

```
curlftpfs myaccount:mypassword?!@thefptserver.com
```

but it gives me "bash: !@theftpsever.com: event not found"

How do I escape those characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enclose it in single quotes:

```
curlftpfs 'myaccount:mypassword?!@thefptserver.com'
```

As you've discovered, the exclamation mark has a special meaning in `bash`: `!@thefptserver.com` stands for the most recent command that started with `@thefptserver.com`.

Answer (score 5):

You can separate user and password from FTP URL/IP using user option below:

```
curlftpfs -o user='myaccount:mypassword?!' thefptserver.com
```

I found this option in curlftpfs manual and hope it helps!

Also found the same answer in this link https://superuser.com/questions/269006/curlftpfs-doesnt-work-for-a-username-with-a

Answer (score 1):

Bash is looking for the most recent command starting with `@theftpsever.com` in your history. This is called ["History expansion"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) and *can* be really useful. In this case, of course, it is not.

You can escape the `!` using a backslash, but it's more usual to use single quotes to stop your shell trying to do this:

```
curlftpfs 'myaccount:mypassword?!@thefptserver.com'
```

Comment: Ok, but my password contains character % and the above method does not work!

Comment: @MarkoFrelih: Perhaps you have a [tag:urlencode] issue, rather than a history-expansion issue. Try using `%25` in place of `%`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding for what I mean.